# SQL SIGN, FLOOR, DEVCAT

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

SIGN(FLOOR((X.RT - O.RD) * 24 * 60) - 2) >= 0

What does SIGN and FLOOR means here? Also can someone explain what is DEVCAT ?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Functions.html) lists the built-in functions, including sign and floor. You would need to provide context for 'devcat' - at a guess, is that the schema your tables are in, or one of the table you are querying?

Answer (score 1):

You can look all these functions up in the Oracle documentation for [single-row numeric functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-AC0E8A99-5097-4147-8295-C88EAC5AA362).

> `FLOOR` returns the largest integer equal to or less than `n`.

> `SIGN` returns the sign of n.
>
> For value of `NUMBER` type, the sign is:
>
> - `-1` if `n<0`
> - `0` if `n=0`
> - `1` if `n>0`

---

```
SIGN(FLOOR((X.RT - O.RD) * 24 * 60) - 2) >= 0
```

Guessing from your magic numbers, `X.RT` and `O.RD` would be dates and you are calculating the number of days difference between the two values then multiplying by 24 to give hours and 60 to give minutes and then round down and subtract 2 minutes and check if the sign is `0` or positive.

It could be more simply written as:

```sql
x.RT - INTERVAL '2' MINUTE >= o.RD
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf1708e9bebe189d4fd78a3aeda56121)*

---

"DEVCAT" does not appear in the Oracle documentation so without more context its meaning is unknown.

Comment: Thank you so much  ! SUM(DECODE(DEVCAT, 95, O.MAX_CUST, DECODE(O.REST_DONE, 'X', 0, CUR_CUST))) --> Here DEVCAT is being used in a decode fn.

Comment: @TiaWane From that snippet, `DEVCAT` is a name of a column in one of your tables.